# iPad application with multiple DetailView and have navigation in detailview

Tags: ios, ipad

i search for a way to have multiple detail view in iPad application and i find the sample code in apple developer site http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html , but now i want to have navigation in detail view which this sample does not cover, i add uinavigationcontroller to detail view as :

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ReportsViewController_iPad *master = [[ReportsViewController_iPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReportsViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

    DetailViewController_iPad *detail = [[DetailViewController_iPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *masterNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:master ] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *detailNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detail ] autorelease];

    splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNavController , detailNavController, nil];

    [window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

but when i run the sample i got error

`[UINavigationController showRootPopoverButtonItem:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance...

`showRootPopoverButtonItem` is a method define in a protocol in `RootViewController`

```
@protocol SubstitutableDetailViewController
- (void)showRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem;
- (void)invalidateRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem;
@end
```

---- ReportsViewController.h

```
@protocol SubstitutableDetailViewController
- (void)showRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem;
- (void)invalidateRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem;
@end

@protocol DetailViewControllerManagerDelegate

-(void) didSelectRowAtIndexPathPopOver:(NSString *)ID;

@end

@interface ReportsViewController_iPad : ReportsViewController<UISplitViewControllerDelegate , DetailViewControllerManagerDelegate>
{
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController;

    UIPopoverController *popoverController;

    UIBarButtonItem *rootPopoverButtonItem;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UISplitViewController *splitViewController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem *rootPopoverButtonItem;

@property(nonatomic, retain) id<DetailViewControllerManagerDelegate> delegate;

-(void)didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSString*)ID;

@end
```

--DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ReportsViewController_iPad.h"

@interface DetailViewController_iPad : UIViewController<SubstitutableDetailViewController>
{
     UIToolbar *toolbar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;

@end
```

--DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController_iPad.h"

@implementation DetailViewController_iPad

@synthesize toolbar;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Managing the popover

- (void)showRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

    // Add the popover button to the toolbar.
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [toolbar.items mutableCopy];
    [itemsArray insertObject:barButtonItem atIndex:0];
    [toolbar setItems:itemsArray animated:NO];

    [itemsArray release];
}


- (void)invalidateRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {

    // Remove the popover button from the toolbar.
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [toolbar.items mutableCopy];
    [itemsArray removeObject:barButtonItem];
    [toolbar setItems:itemsArray animated:NO];
    [itemsArray release];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [toolbar release];
    [super dealloc];
}   

@end
```

So Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where definition of method `showRootPopoverButtonItem` is present, seems like this is not defined. You need to define it.

If you want to avoid crash then you can use -

```
if ([aViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(showRootPopoverButtonItem:)]) {
    [aViewController performSelector:@selector(showRootPopoverButtonItem:) withObject:self.rootPopoverButtonItem];
}
```

EDIT -

I have checked this and found what you are doing wrong , for e.g. code in `willHideViewController`-

```
UIViewController <SubstitutableDetailViewController> *detailViewController =  [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

this is expecting a view controller, while you are passing navigation controller which in turn has view controller(similar at some other position), so you need to alter these codes as well if you want to pass navigation controller from app delegate.

Comment: the definition for these method is in the detailviewcontrollers

Comment: and from which controller you are calling this?

Comment: i am not calling the method, when in the splitviewcontroller i just add detailviewcontroller it run perfectly but when i put detailviewcontroller in the uinavigationcontroller and then add as a detail view in the splitviewcontroller it raise this error. in the code i provided above if i don't add detailNavController it works fine but when i add it to have navigation in detail section i got this error

Comment: can you show .h files of ReportsViewController_iPad and DetailViewController_iPad?

Comment: i add ReportsViewController.h and DetailViewController.h and .m in the main question

Comment: you are right, i correct that and i get viewControllers of navigationcontroller and showRootPopoverButtonItem method call successfully but in this case toolbar is nill

Comment: @ali - so now you need to check where you are adding that toolbar, is that at right place